# Is there a way to map array of _id's to documents in one query using MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, query-optimization, nosql

I have a MongoDB database and 2 collections inside it: `programs` and `exercises`. Documents inside `programs` collection have an `exercises` field that contains a string representation of IDs in `exercises` table, like that:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57da8f955cf29df682932ee9"),
      "exercises" : [ 
          "57da8e01d0649e646afaea4e", 
          "57da8e01d0649e646afaea4e", 
          "57da8e01d0649e646afaea4e"
      ]
}
```

I need to map this array of IDs to array of related `exercises` objects. The thing is, I need then in precise order and including duplicates. Like in that document earlier, it contains 3 links to the same `exercise`, and I need to get an array of 3 identical `exercise`s in response.

Now I am using this query:

```
db.collection("exercises").find({_id: {$in: exercises.map(exid => ObjectID(exid)) }}).toArray()
```

This query returns every `exercise` I need but in the wrong order and without duplicates.

Can I achieve such a result in one query using MongoDB? I know that I can do something like that (didn't test it, just as an example):

```
exercises.map(exid => db.collection("exercises").find({id: ObjectID(exid)});
```

Something like this should give me the array I need, but I guess this is not the right way to do it, making a separate query to get a specific `exercise`.

P.S. I know that I can store `exercises` in a document itself, not using the external `exercises` collection for that, but the thing is, some `program`s may refer to the same `exercise`, that's why I think I need an external collection for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to get a query of all `exercises` from server, then map all of my IDs to values from this array from server. Like that:

```
db.collection("exercises")
  .find({_id: {$in: g.exercises.map(exid => ObjectID(exid)) }})
  .toArray()
  .then(res => g.exercises.map(exid => res.find(exs => exs._id == exid)))
```

Explanation of this query:

- get an array of all `exercises` with corresponding IDs from server (using MongoDB's `$in` operator)
- convert it to array
- map each element of the`g.exercises` array to the element of array from server (`res`) where ID is the same as requested

This is 1 query to request all the data I need.

Hope it'll help somebody.